# Using the SPPropertyBag with Custom Admin Pages in SharePoint 2010

Tags: custom, settings, site-settings

I am looking for some tutorial/solution like is described on the website below. It is a custom settings page which is available in the site settings page with a hyperlink.

http://www.graegert.com/featured/using-spproperties-with-sharepoint-admin-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well whatever was working in 2007 is still working in 2010 (and 2013).

You need to make sure that you store the properties in the `.AllProperties` bag.

The global steps are :

- Create an administration page and deploy it in the 14/_layouts/your-project/your-administration-page.aspx. Visual Studio 2010 (with CKS:DEV) or 2012 (with Visual Studio Tools for Office) has a dedicated template for it. Using InputFormSection / InputFormControls will keep the usual look & feel but you can safely use any input / textbox / ddl for the rendering / UI. The idea is to read the relevant keys on load and persist them when the user clicks on the OK button (into the SPWeb.AllProperties as explained above)
- Create a custom action (from a module) that will create a link to that page at the relevant location

Have a look at all administration page (from the 14 hive, under layout) pick any that you would find when going into the site settings and analyze the combination of InputFormSections / Controls / InputFormButtonSection  to have guidance to make it looks just like native page.

I'm using this in all my 2007 / 2010 / 2013 projects, that's way cleaner than asking IT to update the web.config or implementing a generic list to store them (but it can have unexpected side effect with content deployments but that's another story).

In short, anything you can find online for this will be relevant in 2010 and the nice walkthrough linked in your question is more than enough to put you up & running in minimal amount of time.

Comment: I cannot find the dedicated office or CKS:DEV template  where you are talking about. Where can I find it?

Comment: http://cksdev.codeplex.com/ and http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012 :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Francois. I try to install CKS and my computer says it is existing on my computer. Thats true because sometimes I see the name CKS in Visual Studio. But what is the name of this template? When I add a new item I see: Basic Site Page (CKSDev). Is this the template where you talking about? The other link was not compatible with my vs2010.

Comment: Extra note: I see also Central Administration Page (CKSDev). Is this the template? But I would like to make it accessable in site settings and not in Central Admin. Is this a problem if I use this template?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create a custom sharepoint administration page:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Norgean/archive/2012/02/13/centraladminpage.aspx